# How to read data from stdin, for a given number of test cases in C++

Tags: c++, stdin

This might sound silly, but it's my first time solving programming contests on line. The problem is usually described as:

```
Input:
First line indicates the number of test cases t.For the next 't' lines the data is entered.
```

I've written the following program (with the correct headers included):

```
vector<string> read_strings(int t_cases) {
    vector<string> ip_vec;
    string line, str;
    int cnt = 0;

    while (cnt != t_cases-1) {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        ++cnt;
    }

    std::istringstream iss(line);
    while (iss >> str) {
        ip_vec.push_back(str);
    }
    return ip_vec;
}
```

But this program always gets stuck in an input loop. I've also tried to parse the line as soon as it's entered by putting  `iss` in the first `while` loop. If anyone could provide me a pointer on how to solve this problem, I will be able to finally test the rest of the program.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the lines to the vector as they are read.  The first while loop is reading through all the test cases, but is not saving them somewhere.  Then next while loop tries to reads `line`, which is the last test case read.  Try the following:

```
vector<string> ip_vec;
string line, str;
for (int cnt = 0; cnt < t_cases; cnt++) {
   std::getline(std::cin, line);
   ip_vec.push_back(line);
}
```

Comment: Oh so, once it's read the i/ps it has no way of knowing that a test case has occured?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're starting to learn how programming contests work, I wouldn't recommend you to store all the input given. In general, you can store the number of inputs ***t*** and for each test case, the program outputs the answer for that test before reading the next test case. For example:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= t; i++) {
    cin >> input;
    // Some computations specific to the problem
    cout << output << endl; // Pay attention on how the problem wants the output to be printed.
}
```

If the problem doesn't give you the number of test cases, you can simply change the loop to:

```
while (cin >> input) {
    // Computations...
    cout << output << endl;
}
```

It's usually how I solve problems from programming contests.

EDIT: As noted by @AnkitKulshrestha, if there's more than one input that you have to read for each test case, you can simply read them like this (with three inputs, for example):

```
while (cin >> a >> b >> c) {
    // Computations...
    cout << output << endl;
}
```

Comment: I like the suggestion, but if you're doing operations where you need to detect a newline or any whitespace, you'll need to run another loop inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Also, cin stops reading after a space. So if you have values say `10 20 30 40` then cin holds `10` before some instructions causes the istream to flush.

Comment: @AnkitKulshrestha, for the first comment, although this is more problem-specific I think it wouldn't result in major performance problems (at least I don't remember having to deal with this) and I edited the post for the case where you have more than one input.

Comment: I'll try this out tonight and get back to you here. Thanks for the effort though